# GCM with Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I've been using the Cloud Endpoints with GCM tutorial and have had success storing my data on app engine with cloud endpoints on Android. I'm struggling to find an example of how to send a GCM message to a user when their data in app engine has changed. Does anyone have a good tutorial or documentation on if this is possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Endpoint/MessagingEndpoint class's `sendMessage()` method is what you want to call at the time the event is triggered. See the example [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/blob/master/GcmEndpoints/root/src/main/MessagingEndpoint.java.ftl#L45).

Hope I understood the question correctly.

Comment: Yup sending the message I get, its knowing when the data has changed is the question. I've set up my backend by adding it to Android studio with Objectify. Soi don't actually have any app engine code that I wrote that is running. If that's the case, then how do I have this running in the background to check if the data in app engine has changed? If this isn't possible as is, I have a method to get around it